# Search for tags with prefixes in other language files

Tags: ctags, tags

I'm using Exuberant Ctags to generate a tags file to use with Vim. However, in our project, we have javascript that makes remote procedure calls to the server (PHP). Functions like `getUsers` are thus called `rpc_getUsers` on the serverside. Is there a way to properly use things like `ctrl+]` to jump to the associated function on the serverside, assuming it's a standard prefix/list of prefixes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a mapping from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to a custom function, similar to the one described at [:help CursorHold-example](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#CursorHold-example):

```
A nice addition is to highlight the found tag, avoid the ":ptag" when there
is no word under the cursor, and a few other things: >

  :au! CursorHold *.[ch] nested call PreviewWord()
  :func PreviewWord()
  :  if &previewwindow                  " don't do this in the preview window
  :    return
  :  endif
  :  let w = expand("<cword>")          " get the word under cursor
  :  if w =~ '\a'                       " if the word contains a letter
  :
  :    " Delete any existing highlight before showing another tag
  :    silent! wincmd P                 " jump to preview window
  :    if &previewwindow                        " if we really get there...
  :      match none                     " delete existing highlight
  :      wincmd p                       " back to old window
  :    endif
  :
  :    " Try displaying a matching tag for the word under the cursor
  :    try
  :       exe "ptag " . w
  :    catch
  :      return
  :    endtry
  :
  :    silent! wincmd P                 " jump to preview window
  :    if &previewwindow                " if we really get there...
  :      if has("folding")
  :        silent! .foldopen            " don't want a closed fold
  :      endif
  :      call search("$", "b")          " to end of previous line
  :      let w = substitute(w, '\\', '\\\\', "")
  :      call search('\<\V' . w . '\>') " position cursor on match
  :      " Add a match highlight to the word at this position
  :      hi previewWord term=bold ctermbg=green guibg=green
  :      exe 'match previewWord "\%' . line(".") . 'l\%' . col(".") . 'c\k*"'
  :      wincmd p                       " back to old window
  :    endif
  :  endif
  :endfun
```

Perhaps your function could try `tag` or `ptag`, and in the catch clause it could try again including the `rpc_` prefix.